# Aladdin order API. How to filter the orders

Tags: rest, aladdin

I am using the https://mycompany.blackrock.com/api/trading/order-management/order/v1/orderIds:filter endpoint.

The API returns a list of orders based on a query.
I think I have all the headers and security in place as I am using the same API to create orders with.

I am calling the API with a list of externalIds. Same as in the old order API V2.

```
{
    "query": {
        "externalIdListCriterion": {
            "externalIdsGroups": [
                {
                    "accountCode": "9966",
                    "externalId1s": ["XXX_ed8a8d7e-edf5-4531-b826-15cb2945be2c", "XXX_c1b8f901-9870-4fed-a376-1c04e4db8871", "XXX_cd17dcf2-b9db-4fd1-8982-d3234639a644"]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is the response from the API:

```
{
    "orders": [],
    "nextPageToken": "",
    "status": "3 result(s) processed, 0 result(s) not found, 3 result(s) hidden, 0 duplicate key(s) found in total"
}
```

Am I missing some parameters? Looks like Aladding thinks that there is nothing to return.
I have tried setting pagesize, pagetoken and externalIdCriterion, also some other properties, but with no luck.

```
{
  "pageSize": 0,
  "pageToken": "string",
  "query": {
    "basketIdCriterion": {
      "basketIds": [
        "string"
      ],
      "orderDate": "2019-08-24",
      "portStatusOption": {
        "orderStatuses": [
          "string"
        ],
        "portfolioIds": [
          "string"
        ]
      },
      "showTraderOrders": true
    },
    "externalIdCriterion": {
      "accountCode": "string",
      "externalId1": "string"
    },
    "externalIdListCriterion": {
      "externalIdsGroups": [
        {
          "accountCode": "string",
          "externalId1s": [
            "string"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "orderIdCriterion": {
      "ids": [
        "string"
      ]
    },
    "portfolioGroupCriterion": {
      "assetIds": [
        "string"
      ],
      "orderStatuses": [
        "string"
      ],
      "portfolioGroupTicker": "string",
      "showTraderOrders": true
    },
    "retrieveOrderReservations": true
  }
}
```